# How to concatenate variable name AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs

Concatenate variable name in HTML code like:

`app.controller` code

```
  $scope.name ='abc';
  $scope.abc123 = response.data;
```

`HTML` code

```
   <h1>{{name}}</h1>
   <h1>{{{{name}}123}}</h1> <!-- here i need value of abc123 -->
```

Comment: Is this working? <h1>{{{{name}}123}}</h1>

Comment: Y u wanna concatenate and use? <h1>{{abc123}}</h1> this is just a variable name!

Comment: @VeeraBhadraRao No it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can this with controller as syntax:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl",MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl() {
    this.name = 'abc';
    this.abc123  = 'value';
}
```

`vm.name+'123'` is dynamic key and then get from `vm`

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm" >
  Name value: {{vm.name+'123'}} and dynamic value: {{vm[vm.name+'123']}}
</div>
```

Comment: @gifpif this will help u

Answer (score 2):

Double times curly braces wouldn't work since it tries to interpret `123` as number but you can do so using combination of `ng-bind` and `{{..}}`. Like this:

```
<pre ng-bind="{{name}}123"></pre>
```

Here's working example:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.model = {};
  $scope.name = 'abc'
  $scope.abc123 = "test"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <pre ng-bind="{{name}}123"></pre>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $scope.name ='abc';
  $scope.abc123 = response.data;
```

You are not creating variable with dynamic name; hence it should be accessed as below

```
<h1>{{name}}</h1>
 <h1>{{abc123}}</h1> //as $scope.abc123 is defined in controller
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);

function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.model = {};
  $scope.name = 'abc'
  $scope.name2 = 'def'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{name}} 123 {{name2}}
  </div>
</body>
```